# Is there any way to create compiled files for another OS?

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, compilation

Context: I have a machine in the cloud running mysql 5.7 in a virtualized Debian OS. I am actually using a MAC OS to development and I need to compile a shared object (.so) to this mysql instance.

Is there any way to compile in the MAC OS a binary for Debian?

The only solution I can think is to run a docker container with Debian, set the environment and compile inside it.

Comment: Generally, this is called a [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Comment: You can investigate using a virtual machine hosted on your Mac. Check out Virtualbox.

Comment: GCC is great in being compiled as a cross compiler. You might find a readily set up compiler system (you need the target's system libraries, too) for the task.